# how to execute observable in array Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs, observable

I have an `array` variable named `users`. it contains users id elements.

```
users=[uid1, uid2, uid3];
```

and I want to map this `array` and get users info from *Firestore* like this:

```
let userInfo;
userInfo = users.map((element:any) => {       
    if (element){
        this.afsService.doc(`user/${element}`).subscribe(user => {
            return {...user}
        });    
    }
...
```

when this code worked, I got this error:

```
You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

so my question; how to execute `Observable` in `array` iterate?

Comment: Is that your actual code? And please share your template too. And what gives this error?

Comment: The code presented has a number of syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map your id's to an array of observable and execute them with an combination operator liek forkJoin or combineLatest. The subscription will bring you an array of the results

```
userIds = [uid1, uid2, uid3];

userInfos$ = forkJoin(userIds.filter(Boolean).map(userId => this.afsService.doc(`user/{userId}`)));

userInfos$.subscribe(console.info);
```

Comment: Answers with explanation of code presented typically get upvoted more often that those which simply present code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey exactly bro

Comment: This codes are presented. I though I can easily explain what I do. With this way.Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

thaks @Moxxi I ca run my codes with helps. this my codes; forkJoin not work so I used combineLatest instead of it. anf filter(Boolean) worked with pipe.

```
 this.usersInfo$= combineLatest(
          users.map((user:any)=>this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
        )).pipe(map(x=>x.filter(Boolean)))
```